# Javascript - Change all animation-play-state on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a

```
* {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

in my global CSS, it controls ALL animations on the page. How can I make it so it changes to "running" once all elements have loaded in? It functions like a loading screen basically, but it runs before the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use the * selector to control animation (or anything, this selector is [known to be slow](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-universal-selector)). Instead use a class in the body as helper and remove that class when you no longer need it.

```
body.noanim *{
        animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

And then

```
$(document.body).removeClass('noanim');
```

**{Edit}**

You can filter a little more to match your specific set of elements and replace the * selector for that filter.

I've setup a little jsfiddle with a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/devconcept/jdgzngce/1/) that resumes animation after page has finished loading with a 3 secs timeout.

Comment: I don't see how this is faster, `body *`  is pretty much the same thing as `*` except it doesn't apply to `body`. But yes, you do have the correct solution, adding and removing a class of `noanim`.

Comment: @JuanMendes See my edit. I have to use it because I dont have any html posted

Comment: I agree you have to use it, I just disagree with the performance claims that it will be faster.

Comment: Does not work, the page just stays white (overlay that fades away). I think I'm missing something here?

Comment: @JuanMendes Is not faster if you use it as key `body * div.showcase` is ok. It's meant to be replaced with a more specific filter. Without any html is impossible for me to make an example. I'll update with a jsfiddle.

Comment: Okay so for some reason if I remove the code and put it back in while live-previewing the page it works. However if I refresh the page it stays white, until I remove the code and put it back in. Weird.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen See my demo. Drop the live preview for a quick test and also clear cache if the problem persist

Answer (score -1):

Plain JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
        elements.item(i).style.animationPlayState = "running";
    }
});
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("*").css("animation-play-state", "running");
});
```